# Handling network changes during an active session

Tags: networking, webrtc

I am experimenting with WebRTC. What happens to an existing call, when network state changes? For example a client on cellular network, moves towards wifi. As call drop is not expected in these cases, what measures should be taken for providing seamless calling experience ?

Comment: The Ice Connection status would change and Ice candidates should be re-exchanged. I am not sure, however, if there is already a callback that will signal that change(the renegotiation callback happens with media change, but it may also happen with networking changes).